# Custom dispatch event firing in one sandbox but not in another sandbox

Tags: lightning-web-components, custom-event

I am firing a custom event from child lwc to parent Aura component the code is working in the one sandbox but the same code not working in the another sandbox.
I tried to console the events , the one in which it is not firing a 'target' attribute is missing there .
One where it is working :

```
{"isTrusted":false,"composed":false,"target":{"$$ShadowedNodeKey$$":445,"$u":1},"currentTarget":null}
```

One where it is not working :

```
{"isTrusted":false,"composed":false}
```

child LWC code:

```
 openEmailModal() {
    console.log('record=='+JSON.stringify(this.record.data.fields.FirstName.value));
    let allTransactionString = JSON.stringify(this.allTransactions);
    
    let listOfids;
    let firstNum = 0;
    let secondNum = 12;
    //for(let i =0 ; i<Math.ceil(this.allTransactions/12);i++){
        let allTransactionsToSendEmail = this.allTransactions.filter(item=>{return item.HC == false});
        console.log('had-Checked--'+JSON.stringify(allTransactionsToSendEmail));
       // if(allTransactionsToGeneratePdf.length != 0){
    if(allTransactionsToSendEmail.length != 0){
        let self = this;
    self.isLoading = true;
   
    sendAllAccountTransactions({listOfTransactions : allTransactionsToSendEmail,toAddress:self.toEmailValue,fromAddress : self.fromEmailValue,
                                subject : self.emailSubject,body:self.emailBody,accountId:self.recordId}).then((result) => {
                                    
            console.log('pdf Id=='+result);
            let paramData = {ToAddress:self.toEmailValue, CcAddress:self.ccEmailValue, BccAddress:self.bccEmailValue,Subject:self.emailSubject,
                            HtmlBody:self.emailBody, ContentDocumentIds:result};
            let ev = new CustomEvent('callauraemailpopup', {detail : paramData}, { bubbles: true });
            this.dispatchEvent(ev);

            console.log('ev--'+JSON.stringify(ev));
            self.isLoading = false;
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    }); 
}
else{
    alert('There are no Had Checked transactions');
}
}
```

parent Aura component :

```
    <c:transactionsLWC aura:id="transactionsLWC" oncallauraemailpopup="{!c.openEmailPopup}" recordId="{!v.recordId}"/>
```

don't know whats the issue?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show how you are creating and firing the event and how the parent is reacting to the event. You could also consider whether one org is running Winter 24 and the other Spring 24...